# How can I tell grep to find only inside the files but not in the filename?

Tags: recursion, path, grep, find

I'm working in a project using spring and Angular2 that was started by someone else and I'm trying to figure how is it made

I'm trying to find inside the project the home string, but when I use grep (grep -r "home"), all files are selected because the project is at /home/user directory. Of course this is not an option, there are so many files...

So this is something that I really can't figure out. At least not using only terminal commands.

I know that if I move the project to another dir, it pretty much does the trick, but I was thinking is there's really a more elegant way to make it through.

Thank you for your support and sorry for my odd English.

Comment: `grep`, unless directed differently, will only match file contents, not file names. That's the default behavior. Are you sure you're not piping `find` output to `grep`?

Comment: I'm just doing grep -r "home" 
and the output comes with all the files in my the project directory
it's something wrong in that command?

Comment: @BarzX___  Try putting in a specific directory, like `grep -r home .` If that doesn't work, what does `type grep` return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, silly me. 
At the end, when yarn compiles the angular project, it seems that it uses absolute paths, so when I used grep -r "home" the coincidences where almost everything because the absolute paths, now I really know what I'm doing, and it was pretty much ignorance and frustration.

thanks a lot and sorry.